# Read files of directory using Job DSL (similar to readFilesFromDirectory)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

In the Job DSL, there is the method [`readFileFromWorkspace()`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands), which makes it possible to read a files content from the workspace.
Now it would like to have something like `readFilesFromDirectory()` which gives me all files in some directory.

The goal is to make it possible to choose from different ansible playbooks:

```
choiceParam('PLAYBOOK_FILE', ['playbook1.yml', 'playbook2.yml'])
```

and to populate this list with existing files from a directory. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, shortly after asking this question, I found the solution. 
So the [Hudson API can be used](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#list-the-files-in-a-jenkins-jobs-workspace):

```
hudson.FilePath workspace =     
hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace()

def resultList = workspace.list().findAll { it.name  ==~ /deploy.*\.yml/ }
```

Comment: `FilePath` class has a `getRemote()` method which returns string that represents a path on a remote server.

Comment: This method does not work for the jenkins test harness :(. readFileFromWorkspace() does work in the test harness though. I still see no supported `readFilesFromDirectory()` equivalent which is crazy because its been so long. Is there a way to do this without using hudson methods?

Comment: red888, what you can do is use `findFiles` step in the pipeline calling the `jobDsl` step, and passing the result as a parameter. It adds a parameter that you might not want to expose to all Job DSL scripts, though.